# ClassCastException during accessing methods of an generic class member

Tags: java, generics, exception

I am getting the runtime error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: m.compiler.datatypes.Int cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`

Here are the code snippets:

```
public abstract class DataType<E> {
protected E value;
...
}
```

And here the class Int:

```
public class Int extends DataType<Integer> {

@Override
public DataType<Integer> compare(DataType<Integer> other) {
    if(value > other.value) //here the exception is thrown
        return new Int(1);
    if (value < other.value)
        return new Int(-1);
    return new Int(0);
}
```

}

actual call:

```
        if(lValue instanceof Int) {
            Int lInt = (Int) lValue;
            Int result = (Int) lInt.compare(rInt);
```

if i print the values inside compare the values are right, but even if i check with

```
other.value.getClass()
```

i get the exception. compiler has no error and no warnings.

Comment: Are you sure you don't get any type-safety warnings? Seems the generic type does not match up.

Comment: `if(lValue instanceof Int) {
                Int lInt = (Int) lValue;
                Int result = (Int) lInt.compare(rInt);`

Comment: @Thilo No, I really don't get a warning or an error. I even check every single type of the generics I pass around. I do not understand why `value` becomes an `Int` as soon as I use it but before it is an `Integer`?

Comment: It sounds like the problem is with rInt - how is rInt being initialized?

Comment: At some point, you must have assigned an Int to value... And there should have been a warning about that. Can you make `value` final?

Comment: @Thilo you were so right : ) I used a map to store DataType objects and in my `add` method I pass a DataType to as the new value for the DataType in my map. (So i stored Int in Int instead of Int.getValue() in Int) - thank you so much : )

Comment: @Thilo: Could you post your comment as an answer, so Markus can accept it?

Comment: No, I didn't get any warning, pretty annoying ; )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point, you must have assigned an `Int` to `value`... And there should have been a warning about that. Can you make `value` `final`?